# ¿Cómo leer los datos de un medidor de presión arterial en una foto?

Tags: python, opencv

[image: Medidor de presión**texto en negrita**]

Buenas, estoy realizando mis prácticas profesionales y me han asignado esta tarea, mi asesor no tiene experiencia en esto, así que estoy por mi cuenta, he leído que con python y opencv se puede lograr, pero no sé bien cómo funcionan las librerías que usa, cualquier información es bien recibida.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hankdestroyer  te doy la bienvenida a SOes  y solo quiero recalcar que esta es una pagina dedicada a ayudar a personas que están atorados en una función en particular. tu pregunta es muy amplia para ser respondida, trata de indagar algo mas y de ahí editar la pregunta  con lo que hayas encontrado y las personas así poder ayudarte sobre que hacer para que funciones lo que busques.

Comment: Yo creo que seria mejor que crearas una app para que pudieran añadir esa información y la puedas subir a un servidor

Comment: Hola @Hankdestroyer, por favor edita la pregunta añadiendo más información sobre lo que hayas intentado y con qué problemas/dificultades te estás encontrando. Tal y como está redactada es demasiado amplia. Lee [ask] y [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](/help/dont-ask) para más información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que vos andarías necesitando es un **OCR**. Hay una librería llamada Tesseract que me ayudó con muy buenos resultados. Está disponible para utilizarla desde [C++](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract), [Java](https://github.com/tesseract4java/jtesseract), [Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tesserocr), entre otros. Después están las redes neuronales, pero son más complejas de implementar/utilizar, y a fin de cuentas dentro de librerías OCR hay modelos de Machine Learning que para nuestra suerte resultan abstraídos, por lo que no vale la pena ahondar en detalles.

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda!

Comment: No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que son inciertas o deficientes en detalles específicos. Lee [answer] para más información.